# Is it possible to install all Eclipse plugins?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Possible silly question alert.

Being a bit of a hoarder, when I noticed that you can check all available sources after downloading Eclipse and then download and install all of those plugins I was ecstatic! I don't have to do that all manually! Yet I've tried it twice and each time I try to install all of them I can't boot Eclipse back up (it just hangs on the splash screen with no loading messages). I've tried deleting my .metadata folder and running it via ./eclipse -clean but both haven't helped. Is it just not possible to run with every single plugin installed?

Thanks!

Comment: *All* plugins? There are thousands...

Comment: It probably hangs because you're asking for thousands and thousands of plugins to all start up and get loaded into RAM. Bad idea, bad idea.

Comment: Hey, like the warning said...possible silly question.

Comment: @BenNelson it's not that silly, it's just that the answer is basically as simple as "not enough ram"

Comment: Sweet! To be honest I didn't think I was installing thousands. I thought it was maybe a couple hundred on the default lists, so that's good to clarify!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Hoarding" can turn into a very bad habit.

Maybe this is your chance to learn to you should try to resist the impulse "add more, please".

Keep in mind that Eclipse is a TOOL to help you creating better software. It can't help you when you blow it up to a degree that it is just busy with managing all the things you added.

I would even suggest to act in an opposite way: ONLY use the plugins and features that help you to get your job done. But for those plugins - learn  to USE all the functionality that they offer to you. So, if you want please the "inner hoarder" in you: tell him to hoard knowledge; not things. "Things" consume space, and finally "energy" - there are good reasons that the Chinese art of "Feng Shui" asks people to keep LESS items around.